# Delay + slideDown don't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, delay

I have a question. I'm using a delay + slide down method for displaying some text. 
here is an html code:

```
<div class="delay">
    <p> sth here </p>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function delay() {
        $('.delay').slideDown(500);
    }
    setTimeout(delay, 1500);
});
```

It's working fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Unfortunately it doesn't in IE. 
Do you know why doesn't it work in IE? is there anything I can do about it? Maybe something add or replace ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: What error is occuring in IE? (press F12 and click console, then refresh page)

Comment: I just tested it and it works in IE8 for me, you might be doing something else wrong somewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9kdr/

Comment: Did you leave any console.log statements in your code? In IE8 that will throw an error and cause the code to fail. In IE9 the code will fail unless the console is open.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n6WAJ/ Works fine here, there's definitely something else breaking it. Try putting an alert in different parts of the code to see where it stops working. I feel like it's not even getting to the `delay()` function